# Optimizing and loading external dependencies with requirejs

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, requirejs

I have a module that requires the Facebook SDK. I'm wondering how I should configure loading of the SDK so that it's handled properly by the RequireJS optimizer.

In app:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
      'facebook' : '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all'
  }
});
```

In build profile:

```
{
  ...
  paths: {
     'facebook' : 'empty:'
  }
}
```

As far as I understand it, the code above forces the optimizer to skip optimization of that script. The problem is, the SDK is no longer loaded after optimization.

Answer (score 4):

As part of the build process I was using Almond as the AMD loader rather than RequireJS. It appears Almond (0.2.0) does not support loading external dependencies this way. I dropped Almond and switched back to bundling RequireJS during optimization and it worked.

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs