# Is there a way to lazily set the path of a resource with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

So, I have an app that is using requireJS. Quite happily. For the most part.

This app makes use of Socket.IO. Socket.IO is being provided by nodejs, and does not run on the same port as the main webserver.

To deal with this, in our main js file, we do something like this:

```
    var hostname = window.location.hostname;
    var socketIoPath = "http://" + hostname + ":3000/socket.io/socket.io";
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: "/",
        paths: {
            app           : "scripts/appapp",
            "socket.io"   : socketIoPath
        }
    });
```

More complicated than this, but you get the gist.

Now, in interactive mode, this works swimingly.

The ugliness starts when we try to use r.js to compile this (technically we're using grunt to run r.js, but that's besides the point).

In the config for r.js, we set an empty path for socket.io (to avoid it failing to pull in), and we set our main file as the mainConfigFile.

The compiler yells about this, saying:

```
Running "requirejs:dist" (requirejs) task
>> Error: Error: The config in mainConfigFile /…/client.js cannot be used because it cannot be evaluated correctly while running in the optimizer. Try only using a config that is also valid JSON, or do not use mainConfigFile and instead copy the config values needed into a build file or command line arguments given to the optimizer.
>>     at Function.build.createConfig (/…/r.js:23636:23)
```

Now, near as I can figure, this is due to the fact that I'm using a variable to set the path for "socket.io". If i take this out, require runs great, but i can't run the raw from a server. If I leave it is, my debug server is happy, but the build breaks.

Is there a way that I can lazily assign the path of "socket.io" at runtime so that it doesn't have to go into the requirejs.config() methos at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Did some extensive research on this. Here are the results.

Loading from CDN with RequireJS is possible with a build. However, if you're using the smaller Almond loader, [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366103/optimizing-and-loading-external-dependencies-with-requirejs).

This leaves you with two options:

1. Use almond along with a local copy of the file in your build.
2. Use the full `require.js` loader and try to use a CDN.
3. Use a `<script>` tag just for that resource.

I say try for #2 because there are some caveats. You'll need to include `require.js` in your HTML with the `data-main` attribute for your built file. But if you do this, `require` and `define` will be global functions, allowing users to `require` any of your internal modules and mess around with them. If you're okay with this, you'll need to follow the ["empty: scheme"](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty) in your build config (but not in your main config).

But the fact remains that you now have another HTTP request. If you only want one built file, which includes the `require.js` loader, you'll need to [optimize for only one file](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs).

Now, if you want to avoid users being able to `require` your modules, you'll have to do something like `wrap:true` in your build. But as far as I can tell, once your module comes down from CDN, if it's AMD, it's going to look for a global `define` function to register itself with, and that won't exist because it's now wrapped in a closure.

The lesson I took away from all this: **inline your resources to your build**. It makes sense. You reduce HTTP requests, minify it all and get gzip compression. You don't expose your modules to the world and everything is a lot simpler. If you cache your resources properly you won't even need to worry about it.

But since new versions of socket.io don't like AMD, here's how I did it. Make sure to include the socket.io `<script>` tag before requirejs. Then create a requirejs module named `socket.io` with the following contents:

```
define([], function () {
  var io = window.io;
  window.io = null;

  return io;
});
```

Set the path like so: `'socket.io': 'core/socket.io'` or wherever you want.

And require it as normal! The build works fine this way.

---

#### Original answer

Is it possible that you could make use of the [path config fallbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks) specified in the RequireJS API? Maybe you could save the file locally as a fallback so your build will work.

The socket.io GitHub repository [specifies](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client) that you can serve the client with the files in the socket.io-client package's dist/ directory.